# Problema ao Inserir em uma tabela SQLITE usando RAD STUDIO XE6

Tags: delphi, sqlite, sqlite3, sql-insert, delphi-xe6

Boa Tarde,
Estou com um problema em meu código, uso Rad Studio XE6 conectado a uma base SQLITE,
quando vou inserir valores com ponto na tabela ocorre o seguinte erro por exemplo = 'near "6.75":syntax error' sendo 6.75 o valor, quando coloco entre aspas no insert aparece "'6.75", agora quando coloco a virgula ele insere normal pois o SQLITE consegue converter ao inserir direto, só que preciso calcular o 6.75 com outros valores e a virgula não deixa calcular, então quero inserir com ponto. Alguém pode ajudar ??

Meu codigo:

```
 //q_insere_itens_pedido é uma Query do tipo TSQLQuery 
 //todos os valores estão sendo inseridos como tipo string
 //tentei inserir como inteiro(cod_pedido, cod_produto) e real(quantidade, unitario subtotal)
 //mas a query aceita apenas string
 //FAZER CONTAS E INSERIR
 //========================================================================

 valor := l_produto.Text;
 subtotal := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(valor) * StrToFloat(l_quantidade.Text));
 SUBTOTALFORMATADO := FormatFloat('0.00', subtotal.ToExtended);
 VALORFORMATADO := FormatFloat('0.00', VALOR.ToExtended);

 codigo_pedido := IntToStr(q_pedidoCODIGO.Value);
 codigo_produto := l_produto_codigo.Text;
 descricao_produto := bt_busca_produto.Text.QuotedString;
 quantidade := l_quantidade.Text;


 q_insere_itens_pedido.SQL.Clear;
 q_insere_itens_pedido.SQL.Add('insert into ITENS_PEDIDO(COD_PEDIDO, COD_PRODUTO, PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, UNITARIO, SUBTOTAL)');
 q_insere_itens_pedido.SQL.Add('values('+codigo_pedido+
                                     ','+codigo_produto+
                                     ','+descricao_produto+
                                     ','+quantidade+
                                     ','+valorformatado+
                                     ','+subtotalformatado+')');
 ShowMessage(q_insere_itens_pedido.SQL.Text);
 q_insere_itens_pedido.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Atualize sua pergunta informando a linha onde você declara `q_insere_itens_pedido`. Sabendo o tipo desta variável podemos fornecer um exemplo do seu código utilizando parâmetros em vez de concatenar os valores no comando SQL.

Comment: Qual o tipo de `q_insere_itens_pedido`? Faltou colar a linha que declara a variável.

Comment: @Caffé q_insere_itens_pedido é o nome do componente TSQLQuery, obrigado pela dica do sql injection, mas ainda continua o erro : near "6,75" sintax error. Esse erro ocorre quando tiro as aspas, quando coloco as aspas ocorre outro erro : unrecognized token: "'6.75", com 3 aspas no começo e depois 2

Comment: Editei minha resposta com base no código que você adicionou à sua pergunta. Não se preocupe com apóstrofo, aspas, separador decimal... Em vez disso, use variáveis com o tipo do dado que você quer tratar (em vez de string), use parâmetros em vez de concatenar valores na query, e deixe o Delphi fazer o trabalho difícil pra você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque o seu SGBD (ou o usuário, ou a conexão...) está configurado para (ou é da natureza dele) receber vírgula como separador decimal e não ponto.

Não tente alterar este comportamento. A chave da solução é que você não precisa se preocupar com esta característica do servidor SQL.

Não concatene no comando SQL os valores dos campos. Ao invés, passe os valores utilizando parâmetros.

Ao concatenar nos comandos SQL os valores entrados pelo usuários, você fica sujeito a riscos de SQL Injection e fica sujeito a problemas com formatação de dados (não apenas separador decimal mas também formato de data e apóstrofos em strings) como este que você está enfrentando.

Alterei seu código para considerar usar as seguintes práticas:

- As variáveis que tratarão números devem ser declaradas como tal e não como "string".
- Usar parâmetros em vez de concatenar valores na query.

```
var
    quantidade: double;
    valor: double;
    subtotal: double;
    codigo_pedido: integer;
    ...
begin
    // considere usar máscaras ou equivalente para garantir que o usuário entrará somente com números de modo a não precisar tratar erro de digitação.
    TryStrToFloat(l_produto.Text, valor);
    TryStrToFloat(l_quantidade.Text, quantidade);

    subtotal := valor * quantidade;
    //SUBTOTALFORMATADO := FormatFloat('0.00', subtotal.ToExtended);
    //VALORFORMATADO := FormatFloat('0.00', VALOR.ToExtended);

codigo_pedido := q_pedidoCODIGO.Value;
codigo_produto := l_produto_codigo.Text;

// não use "QuotedString". O uso de parâmetros no comando SQL fará todo o trabalho pra você.
descricao_produto := bt_busca_produto.Text; 
//quantidade := l_quantidade.Text;


q_insere_itens_pedido.SQL.Clear;
q_insere_itens_pedido.SQL.Add('insert into ITENS_PEDIDO(COD_PEDIDO, COD_PRODUTO, PRODUTO, QUANTIDADE, UNITARIO, SUBTOTAL)');
q_insere_itens_pedido.SQL.Add('values(:codigo_pedido' +
                                     ', :codigo_produto' +
                                     ', :descricao_produto' +
                                     ', :quantidade' +
                                     ', :valor' +
                                     ', :subtotal)');
//ShowMessage(q_insere_itens_pedido.SQL.Text);

q_insere_itens_pedido.ParamByName('codigo_pedido').AsInteger := codigo_pedido;
q_insere_itens_pedido.ParamByName('codigo_produto').AsString := codigo_produto;
q_insere_itens_pedido.ParamByName('descricao_produto').AsString := descricao_produto;
q_insere_itens_pedido.ParamByName('quantidade').AsDouble := descricao_produto;
q_insere_itens_pedido.ParamByName('valor').AsDouble := valor;
q_insere_itens_pedido.ParamByName('subtotal').AsDouble := subtotal;

q_insere_itens_pedido.ExecSQL;
```

Veja: [Working With TSQLQuery](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Working_With_TSQLQuery#Insert_query_example)

Eu não tenho Delphi instalado então pode haver erros de compilação no meu código (certamente serão simples de corrigir).

Comment: Muito OBRIGADO !! Ajudou demais deu certinho e além de dar certo aprendi muito com seu código, obrigado mesmo !! Uma pena que não posso votar em resposta util pois foi minha primeira pergunta e tenho que ter 15 pontos de reputação mas assim que tiver volto aqui pra deixar como muito util sua resposta.

Ah ainda coloquei uma função chamada troca_virgula_por_ponto que criei aqui pois o SGBD é o SQLITE e na hora de dar um select sum ele só faz a conta se o campo estiver com ponto ou seja ele esta configurado para ponto e não virgula, rsrs, mas deu certo !!!  

Grande abraço

Comment: @GianEric Por nada!